# Sqlite updating a record

Tags: android, sqlite

This is my first time meddling with sqlite on android.

Followed a tutorial and created a SQliteHelper Class, there is this method inside:

```
// Updating single profile
public int updateProfile(Profile profile) {

    // 1. get reference to writable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    // 2. create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("cpf", profile.getCpf()); // get cpf
    values.put("nome", profile.getNome()); // get nome
    values.put("phone", profile.getPhone()); // get nome

    // 3. updating row
    int i = db.update(TABLE_PROFILES, //table
            values, // column/value
            KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
            new String[] { String.valueOf(profile.getId()) }); //selection args

    // 4. close
    db.close();

    return i;

}
```

However, I have no idea how to use it..

I know that in order to get the profile I do the following:

```
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(view.getContext());
db.updateProfile(db.getProfile(0));
```

But how do I actually update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code updates the profile with an specific `id` in this part:

```
// 3. updating row
int i = db.update(TABLE_PROFILES, //table
        values, // column/value
        KEY_ID+" = ?", // selections
        new String[] { String.valueOf(profile.getId()) }); //selection args
```

So, this `id` comes from the `Profile` object you have just pased to the function.

You should do something like:

```
// get a profile
MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(view.getContext());
Profile p = db.getProfile(0);

// change something
p.setPhone(55598789);

// update profile p
updateProfile(p);
```